# Why am I getting this matplotlib error for plotting a categorical variable?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I feel stupid but I cannot seem to fix this error or find any solution online. Why do I keep getting the following error no matter how I try to plot it using matplotlib?

For instance even the following code gives me the same error -

```
names = list(fig1['day'])
values = list(fig1['count'])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 10))
axs.bar(names, values, color='plum')
```

**matplotlib.category: Using categorical units to plot a list of strings that are all parsable as floats or dates. If these strings should be plotted as numbers, cast to the appropriate data type before plotting.**

[image]

UPDATE: I found the solution - https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/why-am-i-getting-this-matplotlib-error-for-plotting-a-categorical-variable/21758/2

Comment: To me, looks more a warning rather than an error. In the end your graph is drawn. If you expect something else, please tell us your expected result.

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you want the days to be displayed in order, or what?

Comment: How can I hide the warnings? ```warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")``` did not work.

Comment: Are you sure the warnings come from this exact code? I'm not able to reproduce them. Are you running the latest matplotlib version? Maybe you could create a small toy dataframe so other people can run the code as-is? Could you add the output of `fig1.info()` to show the exact types of the columns?

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for answering. Here is the output 


`- <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`` 
`RangeIndex: 7 entries, 0 to 6`
`Data columns (total 2 columns):`
 `#   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype `
`---  ------  --------------  ----- `
 `0   day     7 non-null      object`
 `1   count   7 non-null      int64` 
`dtypes: int64(1), object(1)`
`memory usage: 240.0+ bytes`

Comment: @JohanC  
`a = ['Monday', 'Thursday', 'Tuesday', 'Sunday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']`
`b = [154, 153, 151, 144, 139, 130, 120]`
`plt.bar(a, b)`

Comment: Your example runs without problems on my system (matplotlib `3.3.3`). By the way, at StackOverflow the idea is to edit the original question and add all relevant information there. The comments are only meant for short clarifications.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you so much for your help. Probably something wrong with my setup. Also thank you about StackOverflow tip. Happy New Years :)

Comment: Please, print the content of `fig1`

Comment: @SaayedAlam `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)`. This should work to suppress the warning

Answer (score 1):

Actually the right solution is this, because is more generic, applies not only to calendar objects:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']
# you may try with: 
# names = ['1111', '2222', '3333']

# This variable is a range (numerical values) and we pass it for number of ticks on X axis:
rln = range(len(names))

values = [230, 112, 12]
ax.bar(rln, values)

# Finally, we are setting ticks labels on X axis:
plt.xticks(rln, names)
plt.show()
```